# Objective c free custom progress view for iphone with ability to set background image

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiprogressview

I want to know, is there any third party library or control available for progress view.

Basically I want to set a background image of the progress view, and rest of the functionality would be same as default progress view.

Can any one guide me with some links of any third party progress view control or tutorial with the same feature.

Thanks and Regards,
Saad

Answer (score 1):

try https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

MBProgressHUD is an iOS drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional features.

Comment: Thanx adali for ur response, but can u plz. also tell me that this control provide my required feature, that is to change the image of progress view and is there any example or documentation thing available for doing my required functionality.

Comment: and it is a control like activity indicator, thats not what i need, i require progress bar like control